# Cyclic script execution

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How to make the cyclic execution of the script? At the end of the script i need to run it again. Cron is not suitable, because i need to run the script immediately after the previous

Comment: Do you need to run it indefinite amount or times or  you know how many times to do it ? Do you need to run it only of the previous fails or exit status doesn't matter ?

Comment: @Serg, Yes, i need to run it an infinite number of times. I need to run it if previous fails or been executed

Comment: ok. I'll throw some ideas in a minute

Comment: Answer posted, please review

Comment: Better to include it in the script itself. It is totally simple to do that, in any language.

Comment: @JacobVlijm recursive call to itself ? Sure, that can be a thing. That was my idea initially, but I prefer looping, so as not to edit the scripts themselves. :) In any case, you may want to post that as an answer

Comment: @Rikaz may we ask , what is the purpose of such task ? What is the script doing ? Perhaps we can suggest a better solution

Comment: @Serg thanks, I would, but I am in far, far away on mobile :). Not the most convenient keyboard to post an answer :). I wil do tonight if not posted yet...

Comment: @Serg, i use Selenium script on python. Script does automatically tests my app

Comment: Ah, python . That's something for Jacob Vlijm to do :) He's our resident python guru

Comment: @serg since you're on it, please do! No need to let him wait :)

Comment: @Serg I think Python nothing to do with. I just need to execute a command `python script.py`. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @Rikaz inside the script, you can easily make the script run in an infinite while loop, which is a simpeler solution than actually placing the loop outside the script.

Comment: True , here you just can do the while loop I've proposed and run `python script.py` instead of `/path/to/script.sh` as in my answer.  You could put the script itself into `while` loop, or if it throws exceptions - combine `while` with `try . . .except.. . .` structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic control structure in any sort of programming language that requires indefinite looping is `while` loop.

```
while true ; do /path/to/script.sh ; if [ $? -ne 0    ] ; then continue ; else break ; fi ; done
```

More readable formating would be :

```
while true 
do 
   /path/to/script.sh  # Ensure your script actually outputs exit status
   if [ $? -ne 0    ] ; then  
      continue  # if exit status not 0 ( not success ) , repeat
   else         
       break    # if successful - exit
   fi 
done
```

Of course you need to ensure that your script actually does have return status that equals to 0 on success. You may or may not want to use full path, or `./` operator to run script in current directory , or specify interpreter such as `python /my/python/script.py`

If necessary you can add delay before next iteration starts. To do that, you can place `sleep 0.250` right after `fi` but before `done`

Answer (score 3):

Run them as:

```
/path/to/script.sh && /path/to/script.sh
```

The second one will run if the first one succeeds.

Without depending on the success of the first one:

```
/path/to/script.sh; /path/to/script.sh
```

Run second one only if the first one fails:

```
/path/to/script.sh || /path/to/script.sh
```

---

For real cyclic execution, you can use a recursive function:

```
run_script () { /path/to/script.sh || run_script ;}
```

Comment: Good use of recursive call in the function, +1 for that , but make sure you test the exit status so that to have a stopping point for the recursion. See the comments under the question

Comment: @Serg edited....

Comment: Wouldn't unlimited recursion cause bash to crash eventually?

Comment: @n0rd It will wait for the script to complete and based on the exit status (if false), then the function meaning the script will run..so a single process will be running at a given time until the recursion depth is reached.., I don't think that's a major problem...

Comment: How exactly crashing the interpreter (the bash process running the script will terminate) is not a major problem? Yes, if `script.sh` takes significant time to execute, time to crash will be quite long, but it *will* happen. If bash did the tail recursion optimization, that would be indeed a nice use of recursion, but it does not.

Comment: @n0rd There are many parameters to consider here, it's not a fork bomb if that's what you are thinking of as it's not spawning and keeping processes running.. It waits for the script to complete and then do recursion but doing this the recursion depth will be reached and it will stop..I don't know what you are pointing at now....

Comment: There is no "depth limit" - the stack will eventually be depleted and the process will be terminated with segmentation fault. Problem is that expected behavior is declared as: if `script.sh` fails retry, if it succeeds, terminate. The actual behavior: if `script.sh` fails too much times, crash the bash.

Answer (score 1):

To make your script execute again and again you can do it like this (make sure th script has `chmod 755` set):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test" #or whatever you do in your script
exec sh <scriptname>
```

You can stop your script <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Note that the use of `exec` means that there will be at most one process running at a time, instead of having a new process added each time the script runs.